# Making whole kendo grid editable in angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, grid

I wanto to make kendo grid in angular2 where I can simply past data, I found solution for jquery but I need one for angular. Everyone is editing by cells or rows but no one by whole grid.

This is an [example](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/copy-from-excel-to-grid) how it should work but in jquery (check preview).